# AngularJS - How to change variable on .config() based on window resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design, window-resize

I have this code at bellow and it is working fine! But I need some directions here. More details at the end of this post.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);
angular.module('UserArea', []);
angular.module('angular-responsive', []);

angular.module('MyChef', [
    'Authentication',
    'Home',
    'UserArea',
    'angular-responsive',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'responsiveHelperProvider', function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,responsiveHelperProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                     enabled: true,
                     requireBase: false,
    });

    var device = responsiveHelperProvider.$get() || 'desktop';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
        })

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/' + device + '/home.html'
        })

        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/' + device + '/home.html'
        })


        .when('/user-area', {
            controller: 'UserAreaController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/user-area/views/user-area.html'
        })


        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });



}])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser ) {
          $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }


        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in

            if ( $location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
              if( $location.path() == '/home' || $location.path() == '/' ){
                $location.path('/home');
              }
              else {
                $location.path('/login');
              }
            }
        });
    }])
 ;
```

An this is the provider code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("angular-responsive")


.provider('responsiveHelper', function ResponsiveHelperProvider() {

  var w = angular.element(window);
  var screenMode = getMode(w);
  this.$get = function () {
    return screenMode;
  };

})

function getMode(customWindow) {
  //ecra
  var ecraWidth = window.screen.width;
  var ecraHeight = window.screen.height;

  //resolution
  var width = customWindow.innerWidth() || customWindow.outerWidth();
  var height = customWindow.innerHeight() || customWindow.outerHeight();
  var mode = 'desktop';
  console.log("WIDTH: " + width);
  console.log("HEIGHT: " + height);
  if(width < 768 ){
    mode = 'phone';
  }
  else if(width > 768 && width <= 1024){
    mode = 'tablet';
    if( ecraWidth <= 420 ){
      mode = 'phone';      
    }
  }
  else {
    mode = 'desktop';
  }
  console.log("MODE: " + mode);
  return mode; 
}
```

This code is working very well when page is reloaded. I just need to figure out how can I do this when user is resizing window. I didn't understand how to pass stuff to providers. Could you help me, please?

Comment: instead of config , have a value defined and use it in config or controller

Comment: But how can I change the templates parts that process routes to correct 'device directory' without using .config(...) ? The idea is have one template for one type of device.

Comment: You can inject the value to the config and change route url

Comment: You know, is my third day with Angular. I have no idea how to inject something in the route url. Can you please point me to some link to doc/tutorial/example/something like what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function as templateUrl and return a value from there.

```
function getViewFunction(route) {
    return function() {
        var device = responsiveHelperProvider.$get() || 'desktop';
        return 'modules/home/views/' + device + route;
    }
}

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: getViewFunction('/home.html')
        })

... etc etc
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! But, this just do the same thing my code is already doing. I need some way to make this working inside a resizing event. I have no clue how 'to join' the routing problem and the window resizing problem.